# YAML release pipelines - how to automatically redeploy the last successful deployment to a stage

Tags: azure-pipelines

I am converting a classic release pipeline to a multi-stage build/deploy YAML pipeline. One feature I can't seem to figure out how to mirror is the "Auto-redeploy trigger" of classic releases. Specifically, how to automatically re-deploy the last successful deployment for a stage when a new deployment to the stage fails.

How can this best be accomplished with YAML release pipelines?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gotten this to work by utilising the on failure step of the deployment job.

In the `on failure` step I added a powershell task which queries the Azure Devops API to get the last successful build for this pipeline and branch and requeues that build.

```yaml
- stage: DeployingSolution
  jobs:
  - job: DeploySolution 
  - deployment: Deploy
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    strategy:
     runOnce:
       deploy:         
        steps:
          - checkout: self
         
          - task: VSBuild@1
         ....
          - task: VSTest@2
         .... 

       on:
        failure:
          steps:
            - checkout: automation
            - script: echo Something went wrong, need to restore to last successful build...

            - task: PowerShell@2
              env: 
                ReDeploymentPat: $(ReDeploymentPat)
              inputs:
                filePath: 'Paths to powershell script'
                arguments: '-PipelineId $(System.DefinitionId) -branchName $(Build.SourceBranch)'
        success:
          steps:
            - script: echo All deployed successfully!
```

This is the powershell script I am using to get the last successful build.

```
param(
    $PipelineId,
    $branchName 
)
$ADOBaseURL = "YOUR Azure DevOps URL"

$userName = "ReDeploymentPAT"
$passWord = $env:ReDeploymentPat
$pair = "$($userName):$($passWord)"

$encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))

$basicAuthValue = "Basic $encodedCreds"

$Headers = @{
    Authorization = $basicAuthValue
}

$Parameters = @{
    definition    = $PipelineId
    resultFilter  = "succeeded"
    branchName    = $branchName
    queryOrder    = "finishTimeDescending"
    "api-version" = "7.1-preview.7"

}
$buildInfoURL = "$($ADOBaseURL)_apis/build/builds?`$top=1"

# Get last successful build for this pipeline & branch
$BuildInfo = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $buildInfoURL -Headers $Headers -Body $Parameters -Method Get

$buildInfoObj = ($BuildInfo.Content | ConvertFrom-Json).value

$queueBuildURL = "$($ADOBaseURL)_apis/build/builds?api-version=6.0"

#If buildId is returned queue that build with same parameters.
if ($buildInfoObj.id) {
    Write-Host "Queueing Build Id: $($buildInfoObj.id)"
    Write-Host "Queueing Build Version: $buildInfoObj.sourceVersion"

    $queueBuildBody = [PSCustomObject]@{
        id                 = $buildInfoObj.id
        definition         = @{
            id = $PipelineId
        }
        sourceVersion      = $buildInfoObj.sourceVersion
        sourceBranch       = $branchName
        templateParameters = $buildInfoObj.templateParameters 
    }

    $queuBuildJson = $queueBuildBody | ConvertTo-Json

    $TriggerResult = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $queueBuildURL -Headers $Headers -Method Post -Body $queuBuildJson -ContentType "application/json" 

    $TriggerResultObj = $TriggerResult.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
    Write-Host "Build number: $($TriggerResultObj.buildNumber)"
    Write-Host "Status: $($TriggerResultObj.status)"
    Write-Host "Build starting at: $($TriggerResultObj.queueTime)"
}
else{
    Write-Error "Unable to find successful Build for branch: $($branchName)!"    
}
```

Comment: If the deployment fails due to problems with the infrastructure (i.e., affecting all releases, old and new), will that cause an infinite loop where it tries deploying the last good release repeatedly?

Comment: Correct. You would have to manually cancel the pipeline run, or it could possibly be automated by adding a bool ReQueued parameter defaulted to false to the pipeline. In the powershell script modify the `templateParameters` to set the ReQueued to true `$buildInfoObj.templateParameters.Requeued = $true`. Then just add some logic to only requeue the build if it's false.